# check radio button with jquery

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have this code snippet to check/uncheck radiobutton with jquery.

```
 $.each(options, function (index, item) {                   
                $optionli.find("li").eq(index)
                                    .find("input[type='radio']")
                                    .attr("checked", item.IsAnswer);

            });
```

The item.IsAnswer returns "true" or "false", however the radio button is not checked though in its html view, the "checked" attribute is set to "checked"
[image]

What could be the reason for something like that to happen?

Thanks

Comment: I think there is some ui issues. you have use any plugin for change ui of radiobox???

Comment: @mayur no i haven't used any plugins for ui.

Comment: @Paras Can you demonstate it in a fiddle and try to replicate it.

Comment: @PSCoder I checked in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JpUF2/568/ Here it seems to work except the difference i noticed was bettween attr() and prop(). In case of attr(), the "checked=checked" attribute is set even though the control is not set whereas in case of prop(), the radio button is checked but the attribute is not generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:- Use `prop` instead of `attr`

Checked as an attribute does not take true or false. Presence of `checked` it is implicit that it is checked.

```
$.each(options, function (index, item) {                   
                $optionli.find("li").eq(index)
                                    .find("input[type='radio']")
                                    .prop("checked", item.IsAnswer);

            });
```

Answer (score 1):

`checked` is a property, you should use `prop` method, when a boolean attribute like disabled or `checked` is set to an element, the value is mapped to the relevant DOM property of the element(browsers do this) and `attr` and `removeAttr` methods do not change the properties of an element, as of jQuery 1.6 for modifying properties, [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method should be used instead of `attr`.

```
$('input[type=radio]').prop('checked', function(i, state){
        return !state;
    });
```